# I cannot add Android target platform for packages via IDE

Tags: android, delphi

Just a quick stupid question about Delphi Berlin 10.1.2

I'd like to add Android platform as one of the target platforms for my runtime package... and it seems impossible to do via IDE. Popup menu is disabled when there are Win32 & Win64 added to the list.

Comment: Design-time or run-time package? Or both? Because if you want to support multi-platform, you need to separate these. Only the run-time package should have the specific platforms, and the design-time package should **only** have the Win32 platform assigned, as the Delphi IDE is only available for Windows 32bit.

Comment: Yes, it's pure runtime package

Comment: Hmm, works fine in Delphi 10 Seattle. I would imagine it *should* work just fine in Berlin too. What happens if you create a brand new runtime package and try to add these platforms?

Comment: Problem solved :) 2 hours wasted xD

Comment: Interesting conclusion... I would consider this a feature. But it *should* be an optional feature. No need to offer you to target a platform which isn't even configured in your IDE. But I can still imagine many occasions you may want to target them although you don't have them configured. I might target every possible Android device, but never configure any SDK/NDK in my IDE. It shouldn't stop me from at least choosing to target them.

Answer (score 4):

**Results of investigation: Looks like a bug (or a feature).**

When You create a project *in Starter edition* or *before installing Android SDK* .dproj files does not contain line

```
<Platform value="Android">False</Platform>
```

Result:

[image: User can stuck with old platform list]

Delphi IDE just don't automatically update .dproj file when You install Android SDK...

**But Wait, There's More!**

Delphi Starter Edition automatically remove all platform entries like

```
<Platform value="Android">True</Platform>
<Platform value="Win64">True</Platform>
```

without asking when You are saving project... (except Win32 ofc)

So **watch out if You use Starter Edition** and You want to contribute to some GitHub project that works with Win64 too... You have to correct .dproj files manually before commiting.

**Solution:**

Manually edit .dproj file and add missing platform entry.

---

In addition to Starter SKU, IDE exhibits same behavior on other SKU's when you create project while IDE does not have all (specific) platforms yet installed.

---

The IDE behaviour is a bit inconsistent. It should

- automatically update .dproj file in all of cases

or

- just don't touch it at all

*P.S. I love to waste my time for fighting with IDE design flaws...*

*P.P.S. **Target platform Win32 seems to be unremovable*** :P

Comment: Actually while this can certainly be considered as a bug, IDE behaves like this intentionally. It is not a bug but a feature. Stupid one, of course.

Comment: BTW - it seems impossible to remove Win32 target platform from project :P Even if it cannot be compiled on Windows platform... When I remove Win32, close project and open it it's back :P And manually removing it causes **_Unable to load project blahblahblah Platform "32-bit Windows" not supported_**

Comment: Win32 platform has special treatment. It is required for design time functionality.

Comment: I could understand it in case of designtime package. But why I cannot do it with a runtime one?

Comment: *why I cannot do it with a runtime one* Because if you remove the Win32 platform you can't open it in the IDE and execute it. The IDE is Win32. Why do you need to remove it anyway? Just don't distribute that build version.

Comment: The reason **Win32** cannot be removed has nothing to do with the IDE being Win32 and everything to do with the fact that *Starter Edition is (supposedly) limited to Win32 development*.  Just one of the sticks intended to beat you into accepting the carrot of upgrading.  The fact that you can work around this at all just shows what a dogs breakfast "*Starter Edition*" is.  *Starter Edition* is a shambolic implementation of a poorly considered idea in the first place.

Comment: Clarification:  The point being that Win32 is the only platform supported by *all* Delphi SKU's.  The problems caused by trying to remove it are more likely the unintended result of assumptions in the IDE code that this should/would/could never be removed more than any dependency on Win32 in the IDE itself.  Platforms that may be targeted when compiling a project have nothing to do with installed packages or extensions, which is where any Win32 dependency arises.

Comment: Why I'd like to remove Win32? For example I have a package in which 100% code reqiures Android. So there is absolutely no point in building it for Win32. And if I don't need Win32 why couldn't it be removed? And I expect that opening this project without Win32 target in Starter edition should result with warning _"You cannot build this project using Starter Edition"_. This seems logical for me...

Answer (score 1):

### Starter Edition

Delphi Starter Edition specifically does not support anything other than Win32 development.  This is one of the limitations that differentiates Starter from other Delphi SKU's:

[image]

The fact that you can contrive to make Starter Edition "support" anything other than Win32 at all does indeed indicate a bug.

But the bug is in the Starter Edition's attempts to limit it's own capabilities.

If the bug is ever fixed then it would not remove the need for workarounds but rather ensure that any such work-arounds no longer work at all!

### Pro Edition

Pro Edition similarly does not support all platforms "out of the box" so if you do not have support for certain platforms installed then the IDE is again taking (clumsy) steps to limit you to your [apparently] licensed features.

And again, if *this* is ever "fixed" then it too will be to prevent your work-arounds from working, absolutely requiring you to install the platforms you wish to support in order to create/work on projects involving platforms for which you require a specific license.

### Enterprise/Architect Edition

It is not entirely clear from your question whether you have tested this behaviour with SKU's above Professional, but since the behaviour is predicated on not having "installed" specific platforms then I presume that it does not, since all platforms are supported by default in these higher editions.

Unless the installer specifically provides the option to not install them of course (I don't recall off-hand), in which case you could argue that any "error" lies with the person choosing **not** to install a feature of a product that they then insist on trying to use.

### The General Problem

If you create a project in a product that does not support a platform then you would not expect that project to support that platform.  If you then open that project in a product that does support the platform, should the product add support for that platform to that project ?  What if the platform makes no sense for the project ?  What if you are going to hand the project back to someone else to work on who still does not have that platform installed ?

It might be nice if the IDE would check the project and if it identifies target platforms that are missing (as opposed to disabled) then *offer* to add support for them for you.

But it should not add them *automatically* since if it did this and you were to work on a project in an IDE with Android support and then hand that project to someone with an IDE that did NOT have Android support (for example) then this would prevent them from working on the project (if the platform limitations were *robustly* implemented).

But the behaviour in question (removing platforms that are not installed) appears from your description to simply be a clumsy attempt to enforce license conditions.  Not a bug.

### Ideal Solution

Ideally the target platforms would not be separately licensed "features" and more appropriate points of differentiation provided between the SKU's, then all of these (platform related) problems would disappear.

Comment: I just have access to different machines with different Delphi versions. I share some code between them via Git repository. (most of the projects are targetted for Win32 & Win64) And I hate when I'd like to do some fixes using Starter version and I have to restore all missing platform enties manually every time before commit...

Comment: I understand your pain, but Embarcadero don't want to make your life easier.  They *like* that you hate this.  They intend that you will eventually hate it enough that you will eventually buy (at least) Pro + "Mobile Add-On" licenses.  Making life increasingly uncomfortable in the lower priced SKU's is a long established pattern at Embarcadero, so don't expect this to change.  It's not a bug, it's a feature (in the eyes of their sales and marketing department).

Comment: @Deltics Just adding platform to project is not enough to compile anything if you don't have the license (compiler) installed. Furthermore, current state of things is that if you created project with IDE that does not have specific platform installed, you can never add anything else to that project even if you are opening project with IDE that does have them. Manually editing project just for that is huge PITA.

Comment: Right.  The deliberate removal of the platform entries from the project is not necessary to limit the licensed capabilities which are imposed elsewhere.  So doing so can only be a deliberate act to make it difficult to use a cheaper SKU to collaborate on projects with people using higher priced SKU's.  I'm not saying that it is supposed to make sense to the user/customer.  It is *designed* to make life uncomfortable and awkward in order try to force people to upgrade in the absence of other compelling reasons to do so.  This is the Embarcadero way.  Better get used to it.

Comment: The "work-around" currently "works" to the extent that you can still *open* these projects at all, to work on them, requiring you to re-add any platform entries manually (outside the IDE) before you check-in or push your changes for others to work on.  Embarcadero can't stop you simply editing DPROJ markup as required in Notepad etc (I'm sure they would if they could).  Any "fix" is more likely to prevent you from opening projects in the first place if they contain platforms not supported by your license.  So that you will have to "fix" such dproj's before AND after working on them.