# Convert DLL from Windows to LINUX

Tags: linux, delphi

I'm using the lastest DELPHI version 10.2.3   with LINUX support and I already managed to compile a console application using  the platform **LINUX 64 bit**  and execute this code on my UBUNTU client computer.

Now I wanted to convert a larger project for LINUX.

Question  is now : for a exsting DLL which compiles fine for with **WIN64**, how to add now LINUX support, the add platform buttom  in Delphi does not provide the **LINUX 64 BIT**  platform for the existing project

[image: target is a shared Object for LINUX and a DLL for windows]

Comment: You probably can't very easily. The existing project is probably a VCL one, which is not multi-platform. You would first need to convert it to the Firemonkey platform.

Comment: no - I know on the LIMITs of existing DELPHI 10.2.3. version  , my  existing code I want to convert  is just CONSOLE , no VCL or FMX content

Comment: Can you create a new shared object project targeting Linux and add your code to it.

Comment: I'm somewhat confused. Your title says **DLL**, but your text says **console application**. A DLL is a dynamically linked library, and needs to be loaded by an application of some sort. A console application is a stand-alone application that produces output to the terminal (console). They're not the same thing. Which is it?

Comment: @Ken First paragraph explains that console app has been converted. Remainder talks about a different project which has a DLL.

Comment: I run a tiny console application as a first test,   now I  want to convert a larger console application which uses some dll 's ,  I failed to switch to LINUX platform in Delphi and  have  no information  how to keep code for both platforms.  Create a new shared object - can I compile this then for windows as well ?

Comment: @David: Title says DLL. First paragraph says console application (and says nothing about converting anything - it says *managed to compile a*, not *managed to convert and compile a*). Third paragraph is back to DLL. Again, the question is unclear.

Comment: @user9044066: There's no simple answer to your question without having more information about the DLL. Is there anything Windows-specific in any of the uses clauses in the DLL (Windows, Forms, ActiveX, Ole*, ComCtl, etc.)? You're going to need to provide more information, I'm afraid.

Comment: @Ken It's pretty clear. I already explained what is going on. If you can't grasp that it's on you. Of course, it doesn't make it an answerable question though.

Comment: @David: Please don't start. What you explained is irrelevant; it's not what the poster (or their [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9044066/user9044066)) says.

Comment: @user I'd expect a single project to be able to target both Windows and Linux. Why not try?

Comment: If you are asking how to add Linux as platform to existing project, take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42126708/i-cannot-add-android-target-platform-for-packages-via-ide

Comment: @Dalija :  what is shown in your link does not work for my existing dll , that why I wrote this post

Comment: @ ken :  windows, forms, VCL , FMX for sure is not inside the DLL and the included others files,  is there a list of  units which might block to add LINUX64bit as a new additional platform ??

Comment: Can you create a new shared object project targeting Linux and add your code to it?

Comment: create an new empty so I can do, also send to UNIX.... will evaluate adding my code to the new project next  - but this is not the solution I#m looking for - painful stupid work of copy code by hand into new projects

Comment: For heaven's sake. I'm not suggesting this is the solution. I ask if you could even do that. Once you have succeeded in doing that you can inspect the two dproj files for differences. That said, adding a bunch of pas files to a project takes minutes. Hardly tedious. And no copying.

Comment: I expect that short of manually fiddling with the .dproj (or using Uwe's Project Magician: https://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2018/05/17/keep-your-project-files-clean-with-project-magician/), it's the only way of being able to add Linux as a platform, i.e. create a new project, then add the units, which is trivial.

Comment: What's in the DLL's projecf (.dpr) file? I don't think you're going to get much more help without showing some code from the DLL. (BTW, to comment to someone, use the at sign + username without a space between them, like @user9044066 - if you put a space in there, it doesn't work. I didn't get your earlier comment until I just happened to see it now.)

Comment: @user9044066 It would save us all a lot of time if you have provided as much as information as possible within your question. Including what have you tried and what didn't work. Please read about [mcve]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to add platform, that wasn't available, when project was created. To fix this, you will need to delete dproj-file and let IDE recreate it.

Comment: Why was this answer voted down? It seems to be a perfectly valid solution (even better than my comment in the question)

Comment: @Dave The problem with deleting the dproj file is that you lose all the settings that it contains.